# A generalized Thom Isomorphism

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

The ordinary Thom isomorphism says $H^{*+n}(E,E_{0}) \simeq H^{*}(X)$, where $E$ is a vector bundle over $X$ and $E_{0}$ is $E$ minus the zero section. Now assume that $S$ is a non vanishing section for the vector bundle $E$. In each fiber $E_{x}$ we remove two points $0_{x}$ and $S(x)$. Then we put $E_{0,1}$for the union of all 2-points punctured fibers.

**Motivating  by the ordinary Thom isomorphism, my question is**

> What should be a relevant right side of the following equality(equivalency):

\begin{equation}
H^{*+n}(E,E_{0,1}) \simeq \;?
\end{equation}

What should be a generalized Thom class?

Does  this right side depend on choosing a particular non vanishing section $S$?

It is obvious that we can generalize the main question to multi- point punctured fibers. That is, assume we have m sections $S_{1},\ldots ,S_{m}$ such that we  have m distinct vector $S_{1}(x),\ldots,S_{m}(x)$. We remove these m ponts from each fiber $E_{x}$we denote the resulting total space by $E_{1,2,\ldots m}$. We search for a relevant right side for:

\begin{equation}
H^{*+n}(E,E_{1,2, \ldots, m})=?
\end{equation}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get two copies of $H^*(X)$. In general ($k$ pairwise disjoint sections), by excision it's just like disjoint union of $k$ copies of the original bundle, hence $k$ copies of $H^*(X)$. (An extra observation is that, for one section, the result does not depend on its choice, as any section is homotopic to $0$.)

There's no generalized Thom class: the usual one would do. You can regard it as a class in $H^n(E,E\setminus D)$, where $D$ is a disk bundle containing all the sections. This class restricts to $H^n(E,E_{\text{whatever}})$ in your notation.

Comment: Could you please more explain. What you are considering for excision?

Comment: "For one section", is not necessary that we care  about the following situation:Assume $s$ and $t$are two non vanishing section.Is there a homotopy of non vanishing sections which connects $s$ to $t$?

Comment: Sorry, I was away. "Excision" means the excision theorem/axiom; the standard wording is $H_*(X,A)=H_*(X\setminus B,A\setminus B)$ if $\operatorname{closure}(B)\subset\operatorname{interior}(A)$. Any section is homotopic to the zero section: $h(x,t)=ts(x)$; ergo, any two sections are homotopic.

Comment: Thanks, My question was how you apply the excision axiom in the case of my question, that is what is your $B$. Morover could you please answer to last my previous comment?

Comment: OK, it is **not** true that you can homotope nonvanishing sections through **nonvanishing** sections. But it is not needed. By excision, in your notation, $H(E,E_0)=H(D,D_0)$, where $D$ is a "tubular neighborhood" (disk bundle) about the zero section. The same applies to any section; moreover, you can choose these neighborhoods $D_i\supset s_i$ disjoint, so that $H^*$ splits into direct sum. Thus, it remains to discuss **one section** only (or, rather, one at a time), and then it doesn't matter if it is nonvanishing: just homotope it to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the special case when $X$ is a point that what you  proposed cannot work.

Comment: Yes the particular case X=point shows that the "right side" can not  depend only on $X$, but it depend also on the number of deleted points. So i am trying to underestand the first answer to my question.In fact my question: Does my propose leads to triviality?

Comment: This question goes nowhere. Have a look at the book by Bott and Tu *Differential forms in algebraic topology*.

Comment: at this time the book is not available to me. do you remember a particular statment or proposition in the book related to my question?

Comment: Then read csrefully any proof of the Thom isomorphism theorem to understand why your question is ill posed.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: Could you please explain your objection to the question? As far as I see it, Alex Degtyarev's answer describes what happens (even when $X$ is a point). The question has an easy answer, but one which I can imagine being useful to know, and it seems to be a genuine generalization of the Thom isomorphism.

Comment: As opposed to this  question, the Thom isomorphism is  a  central part of a deep and far reaching phenomenon called duality. I know of two rather different ways duality was generalized: to the cohomology of arbitrary sheaves (Verdier) and to other cohomology theories. E.g.  the Bott periodicity is a special case of Thom iso for K-theory. It corresponds to the case X= point.  In all incarnations of Thom iso, the case X=point is fundamental.

Comment: Also, I'm not opposed to the question.  I think that it had an easy answer  that could have picked up from even a superficial reading  of the proof of Thom iso.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: I agree with you on some level. I was just trying to understand the sentence in your answer. (To me, it seems that what the OP proposed *did* work, even if it turned out to be trivial.)

Comment: I used the term "ill posed" with a nod to math-phyz  where it has a precise meaning.